# Webpack + `create-react-app` | ProvidePlugin Not Loading React as a Module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, create-react-app

** Note: I barely know anything about Webpack.*

I want to load the `react` node module and other modules in Webpack via `ProvidePlugin` to have global access to them.

I created a `create-react-app` and ran `eject` and got access the pre-defined configuration for Webpack `create-react-app` provides.

I read [this post](https://medium.com/react-weekly/never-import-react-from-react-again-thanks-to-webpack-s-provideplugin-69e7feb69e) about loading `react` globally via `PluginProvidor` and read about `PluginProvidor` itself in the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), where the latter states:

> By default, module resolution path is current folder (./**) and node_modules

Based on that, in `webpack.config.js`, in `plugins`, I added the following `PluginProvidor`:

```
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
    {
      React: 'react'
    }
  )
]
...
```

But it didn't work - in a JSX file when I call React (e.g `class MyComponent extends React.Component { ... }`) I get an error that says that React isn't defined (and also a React-specfic error that React must be defined in JSX files).

Why doesn't it work? As far as I understand, I'm giving the same identifier I call in my JSX file, and like I mentioned, according to the Webpack docs, to the path of the `react` module in `node_modules` - both as required for it to work.

My configuation file: [`webpack.config.js`](https://pastebin.com/f5iA6gZy)

Comment: According to the error, did you `import React from 'react'` in `MyComponent` file?

Comment: So far, until trying to use `PluginProvidor`, I have. And it worked, and it still works when I `import` it. It's when I remove the `import` declaration and try to load it via `PluginProvidor` that it doesn't get loaded.

Comment: Its doesnt metter, You HAVE to import it

Comment: But doesn't PluginProvidor do the loading for me? I thought that's the point of `PluginProvider` - that it auto-loads modules and makes them available globally.

Comment: show all webpack config, try new webpack.PluginProvider ...

Comment: I indeed didn't use `*webpack*.PluginProvider` as required (and stated in the docs) - however, this still didn't work. I updated the code in my post.

Comment: link dosnt work, btw try to write an import line and comment it, if it still doesnt work the problem is with how you configured the webpack

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the link, I fixed it.

Comment: *I* didn't configure Webpack - `react-create-app` did, as stated in the post.
Also, I already tested the Webpack React loading by commenting out the import in the file and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's  [not a good idea](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4281) to use ProvidePlugin, and [even worse](https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741) is to `eject` your CRA.

Instead of `ProvidePlugin` use globals:

```js
// globals.js
import React from 'react';

window.React = React;
```

and then `import './globals'`

```js
import './globals';

// no need import React
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
```

For adding plugins to CRA web pack refer to [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired).

Example of adding a plugin:

```js
/* config-overrides.js */
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (!config.plugins) {
    config.plugins = [];
  }
  config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin());
  return config;
};
```

Demo:

[image: Edit modest-meninsky-brb7y]